# Can someone help me with formatting a two-dimensional array display with a for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, formatting

I'm trying to code a for loop to display a two-dimensional array of doubles rounded to one decimal place. However, whenever I run my code it displays only the last column of data correctly, and displays the preceding columns with two extra decimal points. Here is my code:

```
public void calcDistance(double [] radians, int [] initialVelocity, double [][] answers)
{

    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < initialVelocity.length; rowIndex++)
    {
        for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < radians.length; colIndex++)
        {
            answers[rowIndex][colIndex] = ((Math.pow(initialVelocity[rowIndex], 2) * Math.sin(radians[colIndex]))/ 9.8);
            System.out.print(initialVelocity[rowIndex] + " ");                
            System.out.printf("%9.1f", answers[rowIndex][colIndex]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And it displays something like this:

```
20      17.220      20.420      23.420      26.220      28.920      31.3
25      27.025      31.925      36.625      41.025      45.125      48.9
30      38.830      45.930      52.730      59.030      64.930      70.4
35      52.835      62.535      71.735      80.335      88.435      95.8
40      69.040      81.640      93.640     104.940     115.440     125.1
45      87.345     103.345     118.545     132.845     146.145     158.3
50     107.850     127.650     146.350     164.050     180.450     195.4
```

Why do some numbers have 3 digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Hint: remove the line `System.out.print(initialVelocity[rowIndex] + " ");` for now and check the output. You are always appending the initial velocity to the values of the previous loop iteration - see how every value in the first line ends with 20? in the second with 25 and so on?

Comment: Oh! Yes I do see that. Interesting. Thank you

Comment: have you seen my answer? That fixes that exact problem :)

Comment: Do you know why that happened?

Comment: Yes, I tried to explain it in the answer as well.

Comment: Oh, wait I see your answer now! Sorry I'm new here, still figuring it all out.

Comment: No problem, take your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your for-loop to be:

```
for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < initialVelocity.length; rowIndex++)
{
    System.out.print(initialVelocity[rowIndex] + " ");                
    for(int colIndex = 0; colIndex < radians.length; colIndex++)
    {
        answers[rowIndex][colIndex] = ((Math.pow(initialVelocity[rowIndex], 2) * Math.sin(radians[colIndex]))/ 9.8);
        System.out.printf("%9.1f ", answers[rowIndex][colIndex]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

What previously happened is that you output the following in that exact order:

> 20[space]
>   17.2
>   20[space]
>   20.4
>   20[space]
>   etc.

Those appended to one another yield

> 20 17.220 20.420 etc.

You should print the `initialVelocity` only once per line - at the beginning before the inner loop runs. the inner loop-values have to separated with a space.

Comment: That fixed it! I appreciate it!

Comment: @NotSteve you are welcome. Since this answer solved your problem and you are new here: as the one who posted the question you can chose to "accept" the answer that was the most helpful by clicking the checkmark on its let!